# how to get/fetch our facebook group list (android sdk)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-group

I integrate my android app with facebook. I want to fetch (then display) list of my facebook group on my app. Maybe anyone have a tutorial to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the following end point

```
/me/groups
```

Which displays the list of the `groups` the User has subscribed to. But to get the data from the end point you will be required to obtain the `user_groups` permission to read the User's group.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the documentation at:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/